# mytop: least privileges required to run it?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, command-line-interface

What is the minimum set of privileges that `mytop` requires in order to work, without actually requiring super-user privileges.

I feel uncomfortable with the fact that I have to save the password in the configuration file (the less desirable alternative would be the command line), so I want to minimize the impact, should someone get to see the password. The password will still be used only in this one place, but I would prefer to not give unneeded privileges to the (MySQL) user mytop is running as.

The `mytop` documentation doesn't mention any of that and all examples assume `root`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell all you need is enough to run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `SHOW STATUS` on the mysql server, which should mean that you only need [USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage), and [PROCESS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process).

So create an account like so.

```
grant usage,process on *.* to 'mytop'@'%' identified by 'mypassword';
```

If you don't want to save your password, then use the command line.  This command will login as the user mytop, and prompt you for a password so it doesn't get store in your history or the process list.

```
mytop -u mytop --prompt
```

Comment: Note that you'll need the SUPER privilege for some functionality, such as killing threads.  But you probably want to not enable this normally.

Answer (score 7):

I've found I also need to grant SELECT on mysql.* to have mytop actually succeed, in addition to the usage, process referenced above.